# consequences of disabling 'The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service '

Tags: proxy, web, winhttp

I am dba responsible for  several sql boxes running sql2008 standard on Windows 2008r2 datacentre Servers. Every now and again I see a spike in cpu which coincides with the event "The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the running state' and we see a brief degradation in performance, sometimes we briefly loose connectivity with the server.
In order to disable this service what will I need to verify before doing so ?
I am pretty sure we dont use proxys so is this an indication I can just disable it?